How do I get a section of pre-stated code (servo coding) to appear in my "keypad" coding so that I can call on it later?
I am a student in a Robotics Engineering class and I am working on my finals project. My code is shown below but my main problem is that I am entering the "secret code" into my 4x4 keypad and it isn't allowing the "Code Correct!" message to pop up. My other issue with this coding is that since I cannot get anything out of the correct code I am unable to activate my servo. I am meant to enter the secret code (4789 as stated within the coding) to get a message that says "Code Correct!" then my servo code is meant to activate. Neither of these situations are happening when I run the code.
# This program allows a user to enter a
# Code. If the C-Button is pressed on the
# keypad, the input is reset. If the user
# hits the A-Button, the input is checked.

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

#start of servo code
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

def servoMove():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(1, GPIO.OUT)

    servo=GPIO.PWM(1, 50)
    servo.start(0)

    servo.ChangeDutyCycle(10) # left -90 deg position
    sleep(5)
    servo.ChangeDutyCycle(-10) # neutral position

    servo.stop()
    GPIO.cleanup()
#end of servo code

# These are the GPIO pin numbers where the
# lines of the keypad matrix are connected
L1 = 5
L2 = 6
L3 = 13
L4 = 19

# These are the four columns
C1 = 12
C2 = 16
C3 = 20
C4 = 21

# The GPIO pin of the column of the key that is currently
# being held down or -1 if no key is pressed

keypadPressed = -1

secretCode = "4789"
input = ""

# Setup GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(L1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(L2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(L3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(L4, GPIO.OUT)

# Use the internal pull-down resistors
GPIO.setup(C1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(C2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(C3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(C4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)



# This callback registers the key that was pressed
# if no other key is currently pressed
def keypadCallback(channel):
    global keypadPressed
    if keypadPressed == -1:
        keypadPressed = channel

# Detect the rising edges on the column lines of the
# keypad. This way, we can detect if the user presses
# a button when we send a pulse.
GPIO.add_event_detect(C1, GPIO.RISING, callback=keypadCallback)
GPIO.add_event_detect(C2, GPIO.RISING, callback=keypadCallback)
GPIO.add_event_detect(C3, GPIO.RISING, callback=keypadCallback)
GPIO.add_event_detect(C4, GPIO.RISING, callback=keypadCallback)

# Sets all lines to a specific state. This is a helper
# for detecting when the user releases a button
def setAllLines(state):
    GPIO.output(L1, state)
    GPIO.output(L2, state)
    GPIO.output(L3, state)
    GPIO.output(L4, state)

def checkSpecialKeys():
    global input
    pressed = False
    GPIO.output(L3, GPIO.HIGH)
    if (GPIO.input(C4) == 1):
        print("Input reset!");
        pressed = True
    GPIO.output(L3, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(L1, GPIO.HIGH)
    if (not pressed and GPIO.input(C4) == 1):
        if input == secretCode:
            print("Code correct!")
            servoMove()
            print("after servo")
            return 1
            # TODO: Activate Sensor/Motor to move Sensor
        else:
            print("Incorrect code!")
            return 0
            # TODO: Light up LED and Activate Buzzer
        pressed = True
    GPIO.output(L3, GPIO.LOW)
    if pressed:
        input = ""
    return pressed

# reads the columns and appends the value, that corresponds
# to the button, to a variable
def readLine(line, characters):
    global input
    # We have to send a pulse on each line to
    # detect button presses
    GPIO.output(line, GPIO.HIGH)
    if(GPIO.input(C1) == 1):
        input = input + characters[0]
    if(GPIO.input(C2) == 1):
        input = input + characters[1]
    if(GPIO.input(C3) == 1):
        input = input + characters[2]
    if(GPIO.input(C4) == 1):
        input = input + characters[3]
    GPIO.output(line, GPIO.LOW)
def keyReturn():
    keypadPressed = -1
    while True:
            # If a button was previously pressed,
            # check, whether the user has released it yet
            if keypadPressed != -1:
                setAllLines(GPIO.HIGH)
                if GPIO.input(keypadPressed) == 0:
                    keypadPressed = -1
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
            # Otherwise, just read the input
            else:
                if not checkSpecialKeys():
                    readLine(L1, ["1","2","3","A"])
                    readLine(L2, ["4","5","6","B"])
                    readLine(L3, ["7","8","9","C"])
                    readLine(L4, ["*","0","#","D"])
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
#    except KeyboardInterrupt:
#        print("\nApplication stopped!")

print("it reached this point")
keyReturn()
print("after keyboard")

I have tried to use the "return 1" and the "return 0" to get a true or false out of the code to then activate the servo instead, but that didn't work out. I later tried this code where I had stated the entire servo code before as a "def" function and called it on later. None of these options have seemed to work for me yet.
